# Pytest: Asserting multiple calls on a function with a dictionary parameter

Tags: python, dictionary, mocking, pytest

I want to test a python snippet which is requesting information from a paginated API and updates the offset if there is more information available.

Some minimal example code:

```
def fetch(url, params):
    # call the API

def fetch_all():
    params = {"offset": 0}
    while True:
        result = fetch("example.com", params).json()
        if len(result) > 1000: # If there are more items
            params["offset"] += 1
        else:
            break
```

While testing this function, I am mocking the `fetch` function and checking if it has multiple calls with different offsets. Unfortunately, all those calls seem to reference the same dictionary .
Therefore if I iterate though it e.g. 3 times, it looks like this:

Expected:

```
call("example.com", {"offset": 0}),
call("example.com", {"offset": 1}),
call("example.com", {"offset": 2})
```

Actual:

```
call("example.com", {"offset": 2}),
call("example.com", {"offset": 2}),
call("example.com", {"offset": 2})
```

If I instead change the code to `result = fetch("example.com", params.copy())`, it works properly. So the calls recorded in the mock definitely seem to reference the same dictionary.

How do I fix it? I do not really want to always have to hand in copies only to be able to do some testing on it.

-- **Edit** --

I've put together a working example (called `test.py`) that shows the stated behavior:

```
def fetch(url: str, params: dict):
    pass # This is getting mocked

def fetch_all():
    params = {"offset": 0}
    result = []

    while True:
        data = fetch("https://example.com", params)
        result.extend(data)

        if len(data) >= 5:
            params["offset"] += 1
        else:
            break
    return result


def test_fetch_all(mocker):
    side_effect = [
        [1,2,3,4,5],
        [6,7]
    ]

    mocked_fetch = mocker.patch("test.fetch", side_effect=side_effect)

    assert fetch_all() == [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]

    mocked_fetch.assert_has_calls([
        mocker.call("https://example.com", params={"offset": 0}),
        mocker.call("https://example.com", params={"offset": 1})
    ])
```

Resulting in:

```
AssertionError: Calls not found.

Expected: [call('https://example.com', params={'offset': 0}),
           call('https://example.com', params={'offset': 1})]

 Actual: [call('https://example.com', {'offset': 1}),
          call('https://example.com', {'offset': 1})]
```

Comment: I think it would be easier to answer if you were to provide the code you're using for testing - it sounds like you consider it to be a problem with the test/mock code rather than the application code (since you've ruled out modifying the application code to 'fix' it)?

Comment: If you don't copy the parameter, there is no way to get the value of the argument at the time of calling, as that information simply is not there anymore. You may want to rethink what you really need to test here - in your simple example it doesn't matter what the values are. They would matter if they caused some side effect - in this case you may want to test that side effect instead.

Comment: For your example, I would just check for the correct number of calls, and the correct signature of the last call. As I wrote above, that should be sufficient for this use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a stub method and store a copy of the parameters every time the method is called, then assert against your stored copy.

I made a few modifications to your working example to make it work:

```
def test_fetch_all(mocker):
    return_values = [
        [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        [6, 7]
    ]
    call_parameters = []

    def my_fetch(url: str, params: dict):
        call_parameters.append((url, params.copy()))
        return return_values.pop(0)

    mocker.patch("test.fetch", side_effect=my_fetch)

    assert fetch_all() == [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

    assert call_parameters == [
        ("https://example.com", {"offset": 0}),
        ("https://example.com", {"offset": 1})
    ]
```